# How do I finish a css animation with loading a new URL?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have in mind a few fade-ins, then a fade-out, and ending in a new page being load (target=self).
From some googling, it seems css animation doesn't foresee the last step (fetching a new URL).

Is there a simple way to do that? The starting page will be loading jquery.
Somehow the new URL has to wait until the animation ends.

**Update**

In the end, I used [**this css animation tutorial**](http://cssnerd.com/2012/04/03/jquery-like-pure-css3-image-fade-in/) to make a 5-second animation, inserted all css in the `<head>` and pasted the images in the page in base64 (no further HTTP requests), checked the resulting file size (11Kb), checked Google Analytics to see my average page load times for files that size (less than 1 second) then added to the page `<META http-equiv="refresh" content="8; url=page2.html">`. Feels like something from the 1990s, but it works.

Comment: Is this *real* CSS animation or jQuery animation?

Comment: css animation (jquery is there for something else on the page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the animation time is always the same, you can handle the excact time of animation, and load the page after this time.

Comment: Do you mean using  <META http-equiv="refresh" content="5; [URL]">? If so, a problem might be: if the starting page loads slow, e.g. images needed for the animation, the refresh might kick in before the animation ends.

Answer (score 1):

It depends if your animation is powered by CSS or jQuery, a question raised by a few others, too. If it is CSS-based, you can [listen to the `animationend` event](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/using-jquery-to-detect-when-css3-animations-and-transitions-end) (with appropriate vendor prefixes added to maximize cross-browser compatibility):

```
$(ele).one('webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend msAnimationEnd animationend', function() {
    // Load new URL
    window.location.href = newURL;
});
```

See demo fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/pqxsj8v9/

---

If your animation is jQuery powered, i.e. using the `.animate()` method, simply use the callback function:

```
$(ele).animate({
    // Animate stuff
}, duration, function() {
    // Load new URL
    window.location.href = newURL;
});
```

See demo fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/ad0vtqyt/

Comment: I'd like to just use css. But in your first jsfiddle example I see some animation but no new URL loading in the result frame.

Comment: JSFiddle do not accept `window.location`. There are plenty of exmaples out there how to redirect to another URL with JS: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery-javascript

Comment: OK, will check it out and get back. I have no idea where I insert window.location

Answer (score 0):

how are you firing the animation, you mentioned jquery, so if you are using jquery for the animation you can always use the callback to load your page or set a timeout etc

```
$('.someElement'.animate({}, timeFrame, function () {

    // fire cod ein here or set a timeout for when the whole animation is done
    setTimout(function () {
        //code here
    }, timeForAnimationToFinish):

});
```

[jquery animate docs](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

if you are adding classes and using css3 transition, you could always do:

```
$('#someThing').addClass('animateMeFor30Seconds', function () {
    var someThing = $(this);
    setTimeout(function () {
        //next animation
    }, 30000);
});
```

It's not the greatest, but it will pass your unit tests and allow you to refector :-)

Comment: I wasn't going to use jquery for the animation, just css, like here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jlfdG (I'm using jquery for some other stuff). In your suggested code, what's going to load the new URL? (I'm a bit weak on javascript)... Or, to keep it simple (for me), taking this code from codepen, <body>
<div class="box fade-in one">
look at me fade in</div></body> how do I load a new URL?

Comment: you could do it like in the code pen, using the same css, but use jquery ONLY to add the class to the elements, then you'd still get the callback. I wouldnt normally recomend jquery, but if your loading it in anyway . .